# Adding nodes to mvcsitemap in code

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I am building a simple CMS that stores the navigation/sitemap/site structure in a database table. When the app starts up I can create my sitemap nodes dynamically based on the data from that table.

The problem I am having is when a new record is added to the table or an existing one is updated while the app is running I need to rebuild the sitemap structure. Seems simple enough but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support of clearing/rebuilding the sitemap on-the-fly.
But you could implement this yourself quite easily by implementing a custom sitemapprovider deriving from `MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider`, and create a method used to clear the cache, using the protected `Clear()` method. Example:

```
public class CustomSiteMapProvider : DefaultSiteMapProvider
{
  public void ClearSiteMap()
  {
    Clear();
  }
}
```

I haven't tried it but it should work. Remember to changed the web.config file to use the custom sitemapprovider instead of `DefaultSiteMapProvider`.

Comment: I have a custom sitemap provider already in place, I'll give this a try.. thanks